# Python web crawler requests call

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

im currently trying to build a multiprocessing python crawler. My problem is the requests calls somehow get stuck (after crawling 2-3k pages). I can´t replicate the reason for this.

Below you find the function (being a part of my class) for the http connection. If someone has an idea this would be great.

```
 def getPage(self, url):
    if url[url.find("://")+3:] not in self.visited:
        try:
            with closing(self.session.get(url=url, timeout=3.0, stream=True)) as r:
                if r.headers['content-type'].find('text/html') == -1:
                    #print("HEAD FAILED :'%s' -- %s" % (url, os.getpid()))
                    r.close()
                else:
                    timeout = 3
                    startTime = time.time()
                    body = []
                    for line in r.iter_lines(chunk_size=512, decode_unicode=None, delimiter=None):
                        body.append(line)
                        if time.time() > (startTime + timeout):
                            #print("Content too Long URL: 's%'" % (url))
                            r.close()
                            return False
                    content = b''.join(body)
                    #print("GET OK '%s'" % (url))
                    return [content, r.status_code, r.headers, r.elapsed]
        except:
            pass
    return False
```

I already checked my http connections using HTTPScoop. 
Sometimes connections keep receiving data forever.

Comment: try to remove `try,,,except` statements and see what happens.

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to use a catch-all `except:`, because this can hide a variety of errors.